# String manipulation in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list containing hundreds of sub lists. The list is from a database table and the sub lists are the rows of that table, so the sub lists all have the same number of entries, and the entries are in the same format as in the corresponding sub lists. Here is an example:

```
persons = [['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21-0049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9/30-6', 'Green']] ...etc
```

How can I edit all the 5th fields to remove any '-'and '/' signs?

After removing the unwanted signs, how could I make a new list containing all the info on the persons where 1) the 5th field 2nd last figure is a 4, and 2) the 6th field color is 'Blue'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is list comprehension.

```
persons = [p[:4]+[p[4].replace('-','').replace('/',''),p[5]] for p in persons]
p4 = [p for p in persons if p[4][-2]=='4']
pblue = [p for p in persons if p[5]=='Blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing the `-` and `/`, you can do:

```
persons = [['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21-0049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9/30-6', 'Green']]

for i in persons:
    i[4] = i[4].replace('-','').replace('/','')

print persons

[OUTPUT]
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '210049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9306', 'Green']]
```

For your second question, you can do:

```
b = [x for x in persons if x[4][-2] == '4' and x[5]=='Blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
for i in range(len(persons)):
    persons[i][4] = persons[i][4].replace('-', '').replace('/', '')
```

Or

```
import re
for i in range(len(persons)):
    persons[i][4] = re.sub('/-', '', persons[i][4])
```

Then

```
newList1 = [person for person in persons if person[4][-2] == '4']
```

and

```
newList2 = [person for person in persons if person[5] == 'Blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
persons = [
    ['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21-0049', 'Green'],
    ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9/30-6', 'Green'],
]

clean1 = [[aa, bb, cc, dd, ee.replace('/','').replace('-',''), ff] for [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] in persons]

def clean(ins):
    outs = ins
    outs = outs.replace('/', '')
    outs = outs.replace('-', '')
    return outs

clean2 = [[aa, bb, cc, dd, clean(ee), ff] for [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] in persons]

print clean1
print clean2

def modify1(s):
    e = list(s)
    e[-2] = '4'
    return ''.join(e)

modified1 = [[aa, bb, cc, dd, modify1(ee), 'Blue'] for [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] in clean1]

def modify2(s):
    return s[:-2] + '4' + s[-1]

modified2 = [[aa, bb, cc, dd, modify2(ee), 'Blue'] for [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] in clean1]

print modified1
print modified2
```

Output:

```
# persons
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21-0049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9/30-6', 'Green']]

# clean
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21 0049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9 30 6', 'Green']]
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21 0049', 'Green'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9 30 6', 'Green']]

# modified
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21 0049', 'Blue'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9 3046', 'Blue']]
[['2014-2-20', 'Ivan', 'Jones', 'Moscow', '21 0049', 'Blue'], ['2014-1-12', 'Mike', 'Dyson', 'Glasgow', '9 3046', 'Blue']]
```

All methods are simple list comprehensions, with different options to consider, depending on your exact requirements.